# angular2 reactiveforms: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I can't get my child-formgroup to work. Can't find why..
The error i see in console is: "formGroup expects a FormGroup instance."

**My Component**

```
    constructor(private _formBuilder:FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
            this.form = this._formBuilder.group({
                email: ['', [Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator]],
                oldPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
                passwords: this._formBuilder.group({
                    newPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
                    confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
                }, {validator: ValidationService.areEqual})

            });
    }
```

**My HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
        <div [formGroup]="passwords">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>New password</label>
                <input formControlName="newPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Confirm password</label>
                <input formControlName="confirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm password" type="password">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nested formgroup should be:

```
<div formGroupName="passwords">
```

instead of

```
<div [formGroup]="passwords">
```

Here's a

### [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0elsgGf80zGwkcTfPHI7?p=preview)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! :)